# How to name views-exposed-form.tpl.php per views display

Tags: views, theming

I tried `views-exposed-form--"view_name"--"display_name".tpl.php` but it doesn't work. Is it possible to make a template file which applies only to the exposed filter of a views display?

I have two exposed filters from two different displays within a same view, and I would like to theme the two exposed filters differently by two template files.

Comment: No. I am trying. But it's not working.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question. Perhaps it would be better to ask the question again and explain how and why the existing solution does not work for you'?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/76215)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is possible in Drupal ;)

Probably Views does not automagically provide template suggestions for the exposed filter, like it does for the fields themselves. So you will need to do a little bit more work for this one:

1. Use the the [devel_themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module to find out what function/template is theming that exposed filter.
2. Create a *preprocessor* for that theme function/template. In your preprocessor you can then insert dynamic template suggestions that will fire off based on any condition you want. You can create this preprocessor either in your custom theme's template.php file or in one of your custom modules. [This D.O. article](http://drupal.org/node/223440#custom-suggestions) will guide you with creating the dynamic template suggestion.

I will assume that you will be displaying different Views displays based on a URL path. If this were the case, then you can use Drupal's [`arg()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) function in your preprocessor to figure out what is the View display that you are currently displaying, and construct your template suggestion using that information.

Once you've setup your suggestions properly, then Drupal would automatically call the appropriate template and voilá, you have different filter templates based on the path (or any other condition that you specify in your preprocessor).

Answer (score 25):

For Drupal 7, you can use views-exposed-form--view_name--display_name.tpl.php (Replace underscores with dashes in view name and display name.)

It worked for me that way.

Comment: This worked form me. Here is an example of my exposed form template name: views-exposed-form--trunk_shows--panel-pane-1.tpl.php

Comment: Even though your views-exposed-form--view_name--display_name.tpl.php may not be listed when you do this, on adding your new template file you should also edit the view, click on the Advanced->Other->Theme->Information, and then click the Rescan Template Files button.

Comment: You don't need the display name, if you don't need to be that specific. For my block view, "Events View", naming my template file "views-exposed-form--events-view.tpl.php" worked for me. Thanks, @kaimlaluno. This should probably be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

in drupal8

> /admin/structure/views/view/event_related

would be

> views-exposed-form--event_related.html.twig

Answer (score 1):

For drupal 8, theme debug mode does not display the available template suggestions. You can find out which ones are avaliable using kint() or create new ones in this hook:

```
/**
 * Implements template_theme_suggestions_node_HOOK_alter().
 * Add theme suggestions to the view exposed forms.
 */
function YOUR_THEME_theme_suggestions_views_exposed_form_alter(&$suggestions, $vars, $hook) {
  kint($vars['form']['#theme']);
  //$suggestions[] = 'views__exposed__form__' . $anything; 
}
```